# Which is a hypergeometric distribution?

Tags: statistics, descriptive-statistics

I think it is the 2nd experiment, but can someone explain why, and why isn't the other distribution a hypergeometric?
Experiment 1- You are picking 100 people pout 220 million people, out of that 100 how many of them are male if 50 percent are males.
Experiment 2- You flip a coin to decide to drives the car, and assume you have to drive the car 50 times this week, and the coin is fair?
Which one is a "hypergeometric distribution"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The **hypergeometric distribution** describes the probability of $k$
>   successes in $n$ draws, without replacement, from a finite population
>   of size $N$ that contains exactly $K$ successes, wherein each draw is
>   either a success or a failure. In contrast, the **binomial distribution**
>   describes the probability of $k$ successes in $n$ draws with
>   replacement.

Therefore the first problem corresponds to hypergeometric distribution, whereas the second corresponds to the binomial.